# Getting a count of unique strings from a List<string[]> into a dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I want to input a `List<string[]>` and

The output is a dictionary where the keys are unique strings used for an index and the values is an array of floats with each position in the array representing the count of the key for a `string[]` in the `List<string[]>`

So far here is what I attempted

```
static class CT
{
    //Counts all terms in array
    public static Dictionary<string, float[]> Termfreq(List<string[]> text)
    {
        List<string> unique = new List<string>();

        foreach (string[] s in text)
        {
            List<string> groups = s.Distinct().ToList();
            unique.AddRange(groups);
        }

        string[] index = unique.Distinct().ToArray();

        Dictionary<string, float[]> countset = new Dictionary<string, float[]>();


         return countset;
    }

}



 static void Main()
    {
        /* local variable definition */


        List<string[]> doc = new List<string[]>();
        string[] a = { "That", "is", "a", "cat" };
        string[] b = { "That", "bat", "flew","over","the", "cat" };
        doc.Add(a);
        doc.Add(b);

       // Console.WriteLine(doc);


        Dictionary<string, float[]> ret = CT.Termfreq(doc);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, float[]> kvp in ret)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

        }


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

I got stuck on the dictionary part. What is the most effective way to implement this?

Comment: Why would you use `float` here? What is ever going to be a non-integer value?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the expected output?

Comment: Ideally with a more useful input where there are words occurring more than once...

Comment: @JonSkeet if I want to do any math operations float allows decimals.

Comment: But the count will never be anything other than an integer. If you want to convert it to an array which means something other than a count, I'd personally create a new array at that point, for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you could use something like:

```
var dictionary = doc
    .SelectMany(array => array)
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(word => word,
                  word => doc.Select(array => array.Count(x => x == word))
                             .ToArray());
```

In other words, first find the distinct set of words, then for each word, create a mapping.

To create a mapping, look at each array in the original document, and find the count of the occurrences of the word in that array. (So each array maps to an `int`.) Use LINQ to perform that mapping over the whole document, with `ToArray` creating an `int[]` for a particular word... and that's the value for that word's dictionary entry.

Note that this creates a `Dictionary<string, int[]>` rather than a `Dictionary<string, float[]>` - it seems more sensible to me, but you could always cast the result of `Count` to `float` if you *really* wanted to.