# C# How to add a list to a dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a histogram using a dictionary. I started off with a giant string that I then converted to an array of strings, and then a list. From there I need need to make a histogram directory that takes my string list.

I don't have much already because I only just started and am just starting to learn about Dictionaries.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Speach;
            Speach = "I say to you today, my friends, so even though we face the difficulties of today and tomorrow, I still have a dream. It is a dream deeply rooted in the American dream. " +
            "I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed: We hold these truths to be self-evident: that all men are created equal. " +
            "I have a dream that one day on the red hills of Georgia the sons of former slaves and the sons of former slave owners will be able to sit down together at the table of brotherhood. " +
            "I have a dream that one day even the state of Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of freedom and justice. " +
            "I have a dream that my four little children will one day live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color of their skin but by the content of their character. " +
            "I have a dream today. I have a dream that one day, down in Alabama, with its vicious racists, with its governor having his lips dripping with the words of interposition and nullification; one day right there in Alabama, little black boys and black girls will be able to join hands with little white boys and white girls as sisters and brothers. " +
            "I have a dream today. I have a dream that one day every valley shall be exalted, every hill and mountain shall be made low, the rough places will be made plain, and the crooked places will be made straight, and the glory of the Lord shall be revealed, and all flesh shall see it together. " +
            "This is our hope. This is the faith that I go back to the South with. With this faith we will be able to hew out of the mountain of despair a stone of hope. With this faith we will be able to transform the jangling discords of our nation into a beautiful symphony of brotherhood. " +
            "With this faith we will be able to work together, to pray together, to struggle together, to go to jail together, to stand up for freedom together, knowing that we will be free one day. " +
            "This will be the day when all of God's children will be able to sing with a new meaning, My country, 'tis of thee, sweet land of liberty, of thee I sing. Land where my fathers died, land of the pilgrim's pride, from every mountainside, let freedom ring. " +
            "And if America is to be a great nation this must become true. So let freedom ring from the prodigious hilltops of New Hampshire. Let freedom ring from the mighty mountains of New York. Let freedom ring from the heightening Alleghenies of Pennsylvania! " +
            "Let freedom ring from the snowcapped Rockies of Colorado! Let freedom ring from the curvaceous slopes of California! But not only that; let freedom ring from Stone Mountain of Georgia! " +
            "Let freedom ring from Lookout Mountain of Tennessee! Let freedom ring from every hill and molehill of Mississippi. From every mountainside, let freedom ring. " +
            "And when this ha   ppens, when we allow freedom to ring, when we let it ring from every village and every hamlet, from every state and every city, we will be able to speed up that day when all of God's children, black men and white men, Jews and Gentiles, Protestants and Catholics, will be able to join hands and sing in the words of the old Negro spiritual, Free at last! free at last! thank God Almighty, we are free at last!";

            string[] SpeachSplit = Speach.Split();
            List<string> SpeachList = SpeachSplit.OfType<string>().ToList();

            Dictionary<string, int> Historgram = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//This is where I get confused??
            for (var i = 0; i < SpeachList.Count; i++)
            {
                Historgram.Add(SpeachList[i],//? );
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

My question is, how do I add my string list to my dictionary while keeping my dictionary with my string key and int value?

Comment: So wait.. how many dictionaries do you want, and what do you want in them/it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Count each word?

Comment: @TheGeneral, I want just one dictionary and I want it to story all the words in my original string unless they repeat, I know how to check if they already exist in my dictionary but I don't know how to add my list to this dictionary.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do, what do the types you are adding to the dictionary represent? A word and a count of that word?

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes. My string key is meant to be the word and my int is meant to represent how many time the work appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a count of unique strings from a List<string\[\]> into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338157/getting-a-count-of-unique-strings-from-a-liststring-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338157/getting-a-count-of-unique-strings-from-a-liststring-into-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, this solution should work:

```
string[] SpeachSplit = Speach.Split();
Dictionary<string, int> Historgram = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// loop through all words
for (var i = 0; i < SpeachSplit.Length; i++)
{
    string word = SpeachSplit[i];
    // check if your word is already in the dictionary
    if(!Historgram.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        // if it is not in the dictionary, add it to dictionary with 0 occurrences
        Historgram.Add(word, 0);
    }
    // add one to the number of occurrences
    Historgram[word]++;
}
// at this point dictionary contains words as keys and number of occurrences as value
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm not to coding as a whole so I'm sorry I'm not great at explaining my problems. Thank you exceptionally for putting comments for what the code do so I can understand what it does rather than just random code being given to me, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this

1. Splits by space
2. Converts to lower case
3. Uses regex to replace all non alphanumerics
4. Groups and Counts
5. Projects to a Dictionary

**Code**

```
var result = Speach.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Select(x => x.ToLower()))
                   .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]", ""))
                   .GroupBy(x => x)
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Alr0kq)

Comment: This is works amazingly but from a beginners stand point ( like my own ), it's fairly confusing. I really appreciate it though and I thank you for putting this much work into my question.